# Search for strings between same named XML tags in C#

Tags: c#, xml, forms

I get a XML Code out of an HTML Page in my WinForm in C#.

Example XML:

```
<param>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>Number1</string></value>
<value><string>11194652</string></value>
</data></array></value>
</param>
<param>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>Error</string></value>
<value><string>200</string></value>
</data></array></value>
</param>
<param>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>Number2</string></value>
<value><string>2155847</string></value>
</data></array></value>
</param>
<param>
<value><array><data>
<value><string>Print</string></value>
<value><string>no</string></value>
</data></array></value>
</param>
```

Now i need the data for Number1 (11194652), Number2 (2155847) and Error (200). Sadly i cannot search for tags, because they are all named the same. What is the best way to separate the data 11194652, 200 and 2155847 out of this XML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you store the XML data?

Comment: @mm8 for the moment to view it, i store it in a string and show it in an richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the required information to a Dictionary as following.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse($"<root>{xml}</root>");
var dataValues = xDoc.Descendants("param").Select(x=>x.Descendants("string").Select((c=>c.Value)))
                        .ToDictionary(x=> x.First(),y=>y.Last());
```

This would produce an output as the following.

[image]

With the Dictionary in place, you could search for the required Values using Keys

```
dataValues["Number1"]
dataValues["Number2"]
dataValues["Error"]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `XDocument`

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var results = xdoc.Descendants("string")
                  .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you add a root node to your XML data, you could located the "Number1", "Error" or "Number2" node using an `XPath` and then select the following sibling node.

Try the following method:

```
private static string GetValue(string key)
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
    var elem = xDocument.XPathSelectElement("/root/param/value/array/data/value/string[text() = 'Error']/../following-sibling::value/string");
    return elem.Value;
}
```

`GetValue("Number1")` should return "11194652" and `GetValue("Error")` should return "200".